# Iterate through xml elements with powershell

Tags: c#, xml, powershell, xpath, sharepoint-2010

I have some xml files that have different elements. I would like to write some code either in c# or PowerShell that iterates through each element and gets the value.
I would like it to be generic enough so that I can use it with other xml files. All xml files have the same format but the names of the elements differ.

Thanks a lot for your help.

```
<root>
  <list>
       <FirstName>Abc</FirstName>
       <LastName>LT</LastName>
       <Occupatoin>Eng</Occupation>
       <BirthDate></BirthDate>
      ...
 </list>
</root>

----------------------
XML file 2

<root>
  <Trainings>
       <Java>Ab</Java>
       <NET>b</NET>
       <SQL>c</SQL>
       <Powershell>d</Powershell>
      ...
 </Trainings>
</root>
```

---

Another xml has been introduced that will be the base for the iteration of elements in the above xml files.

get the values of the elements above based on the attributes of each element below:

```
<root>
    <Element Name="Firstname />
    <Element Name="Lastname" />
    <Element Name="Occupation" />
    <Element Name="Java" />
    <Element Name="Net" />
...
</root>


[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $xdLists = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $xdMig = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$listfile = "C:\PowershellFiles\XmlLists.xml"
$xdLists.load($listfile)

$xdNodes= $xdLists.selectnodes("//DestinationLists/DestinationList")
$migCols = $xdLists.selectnodes("//MigrationColumns/Columns/Column")

#LOOP 1-----------------------------------------
foreach($xnode in $xdNodes)
{
    Write-Host $xnode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("MigrationFile").Value
    $destLists = $xnode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Name").Value
    $migfiles = $xnode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("MigrationFile").Value
    
    
    Write-Host $destLists
    
    #Check if the xml file to read from exists
    
    if($migFiles -ne $null)
    {
            $xdMig.Load($migfiles)
        
            $spSite = Get-SPSite "http://sp2010:100" 
            $spWeb = $spSite.OpenWeb()

            $list = $spWeb.Lists[$destLists]

            foreach($nCol in $migCols)
            {
                $destListCol =  $nCol.Attributes.GetNamedItem("DestList").Value
                $sourcCol =  $nCol.Attributes.GetNamedItem("SourceCol").Value

#               Write-Host $col " - " $list.Title

                if($destListCol -eq $list.Title)
                {
                    Write-Host $destListCol " - " $list.Title " - Source Column: " $sourcCol  -ForegroundColor Green
                    Write-Host
                    
                    # ----------------------- time to search the exported lists --------------------
                    Write-Host "Search the exported list for the right column" -ForegroundColor  DarkYellow
                    
                    if($xdMig.DocumentElement -ne $null)
                        {
                            $xnList = $xdMig.DocumentElement.ChildNodes

                    #           LOOP 2----------------------------------------
                            Write-Host $xnList.Count " items found" -ForegroundColor Red
                            foreach($xn in $xnList)
                            {
                                Write-Host $xn.Name -ForegroundColor Red
                                
                                $nList = $xdMig.SelectNodes("//"+$xn.Name)
                                $lItem = $list.Items.Add()

                                foreach($n in $migCols)
                                  {
                                  
                                    if($n.Attributes -ne $null)
                                    {
                                        $sourceCol = $n.Attributes.GetNamedItem("SourceCol").Value
                                        $destCol = $n.Attributes.GetNamedItem("DestCol").Value
                                        $destList = $n.Attributes.GetNamedItem("DestList").Value
                                        
                                        Write-Host "Dest Col: " $destCol  "-  Sour Col: " $xn[$sourceCol].Name 
                                        Write-Host $destList -ForegroundColor Red

                                        if($list.Title -eq $destList)
                                        {
                                            if($xn[$sourceCol] -ne $null )
                                            {
                                                if($list.Fields[$destCol] -ne $null)
                                                {
                                                    $lItem[$destCol] = $xn[$sourceCol].InnerText    
                                                }
                                                        
                                            }else
                                            {
                                                Write-Host   $sourceCol " was not matched" -ForegroundColor Yellow
                                            }
                                        }
                                     }
                                  }
                                  $lItem.Update()
                                  Write-Host "-----------------------------------"
                            }

                        }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) with [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath). Assume that you have fixed XML errors and renamed `Element.Name` to be in same case as in data file:

`your_file.xml` fixed content:

```
<root> 
  <list> 
       <FirstName>Abc</FirstName> 
       <LastName>LT</LastName> 
       <Occupation>Eng</Occupation> 
       <BirthDate></BirthDate> 
      ... 
 </list> 
</root>
```

`index_file.xml` fixed content:

```
<root> 
    <Element Name="FirstName" /> 
    <Element Name="LastName" /> 
    <Element Name="Occupation" /> 
    <Element Name="Java" /> 
    <Element Name="NET" /> 
... 
</root>
```

`PoSH` to map'em:

```
$xmlIndex = [xml](gc ".\index_file.xml")
$xml = [xml](gc ".\your_file.xml")
$allValues = @{}; 

$xmlIndex.SelectNodes("//Element/@Name") | 
    %{ $nodeName = $_."#text"; $xml.SelectNodes("//$nodeName/text()") } |
    % { $allvalues[$_.ParentNode.ToString()] = $_.Value };

$allValues | ft
```

output will be followed

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Occupation                     Eng
FirstName                      Abc
LastName                       LT
```

and

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
NET                            b
Java                           Ab
```

Comment: Hi akim, how can I use your code above with foreach loop so that I can add the returned value to a variable

Comment: Adding all values to _associative container_ (also know as _hash_): `$allValues = @{}; $xml.SelectNodes("//text()") | % { $allvalues[$_.ParentNode.ToString()] = $_.Value }; $allValues | ft`

Comment: Hi akim, thanks a lot for your help. I just added a few things in my question above. Can you tell me how can I display the value of each element only if that element is specified in the Query XML file?

Comment: Hi akim, above I added some code that I have done so far. I appologize for not following your example. I am using xmldocument since I found some code that was working to a point.

My problem with the code is, if I have 5 xml files to add, the items of the last xml will be dupplicated.

Any idea what I am doing wrong there? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not an expert in `SharePoint`, but your sample looks like you're extracting values from `$xdMig` file based upon using `$xdLists`. If so, `$xmlIndex` is `$xdLists`, and `$xml` is `$xdMig`. If no, try to debug this code in something like [PowerGui](http://powergui.org/index.jspa) or move your question to [appropriate section of forum](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar requirement where I needed to delve into varying XML structures.  This recursive routine works well for most xml I have run into.

```
function GetNodes($root,$j){
    $nodes=$root.ChildNodes
    $j++
    Foreach($child in $nodes){
       $tabs=""
       for ($i = 1; $i -lt $j; $i++){ $tabs+="`t"  }
       if ($child.NodeType -eq "Element"){
            $value=$root.($child.Name)
            if ($value.GetType().Name -eq "XmlElement"){
                write-host "$tabs$($child.Name)" -ForegroundColor green
            }else{
                write-host "$tabs$($child.Name): $($value)"
            }  
        }
        if ($child.HasChildNodes){ GetNodes $child $j }
    }
    $j--
}

[xml]$xml=get-content C:\Temp\test.xml
GetNodes $xml
```

The output for file 1 looks like this

```
root
    list
        FirstName: Abc
        LastName: LT
        Occupation: Eng
        BirthDate:
```

I combined files 1 and 2 to get this output:

```
root
    list
        FirstName: Abc
        LastName: LT
        Occupation: Eng
        BirthDate:
    Trainings
        Java: Ab
        NET: b
        SQL: c
        Powershell: d
```